# how to prove my 6th grade son knows algebra 1?

Tags: algebra, self-learning, assessment, middle-school

My son is taking pre-algebra in 6th grade. He mastered algebra 1 in detail more than what school can teach. How to prove to school that he mastered Algebra 1? He wants to start Algebra 2 in 7th grade. We are in PA.
Are there any authorized professional assessors available outside school? If I can get my son assessed by outside professionals, would school accept it?

thanks.

Comment: Any answer to this will depend on the specific school, the policies of the school district, and the education laws of the country/region where you live. Without this information, it's impossible to answer your question accurately.

Comment: ... and even so, I'm not sure that your question is on-topic for this site.

Comment: Yes, you need to ask the school.  Some schools may allow a student to take an exam to be placed in a higher course.  I know of one case where the teacher of a course realized that the student was too advanced for the course, and initiated the transfer to a more advanced course.

Comment: School district is refusing to assess my son because it's too much work for them. If my son can prove his abilities, school will assess him. We live in Eastern Pennsylvania (Allentown area). Are there any private professionals who can assess the students?

Comment: Suggest you add the above information to the question by editing.  Add that school refuses to assess son because it's too much work, but if he can prove his abilities school will assess him.

Comment: Can your son take Pennsylvania's [Keystone Exam for Algebra](http://www.pdesas.org/Page/Viewer/ViewPage/8) I during either [May 15-26, 2017 or July 31-August 4, 2017](http://static.pdesas.org/content/documents/Keystone%20Exams%20Testing%20Windows%202016-2018.pdf) ?

Comment: @MikePierce -- The general problem of how to place students in the math curriculum of a new school, based on what they have learned elsewhere, is certainly on topic for this site.

Comment: Did your son learn Algebra I by following a particular curriculum (such as Khan Academy or the Saxon Algebra I textbook)?  Did he perform written problem sets along the way, and keep them in a binder?  Did the curriculum include regular exams, and/or a final exam?  If you can show the school your student's textbook and binder of work product, that might be enough to get the school district to take your request seriously.

Comment: Here is [the form](http://web.mit.edu/registrar/forms/reg/addcredit.pdf) that MIT students use to request transfer credit (for courses completed at other colleges).  Note that it requests the college name, subject number, subject name, date completed, **principal textbooks used including chapters completed**, length of the course in weeks, hours per week of lectures, recitations, lab/field/design, and grade.  It also requests a transcript directly from the other college.  In previous years, the form also requested an official course description and/or syllabus.

Comment: Do you know what textbook the school uses for Algebra I?  Are there any topics that are covered in the school's curriculum that were not covered by your son's curriculum?  Did both courses have similar standards for rigorousness of proofs, for how the students were expected to set up story problems, and for expecting students to provide checks-by-substitution?  Gaps in any of these areas should be addressed before your son moves on to the next course.

Comment: Your school district might not want to take the time to explain their standards for Algebra I proofs, setting up of Algebra I story problems, and checks-by-substitution.  In that case, perhaps you could ask an attentive parent of a child who did well in the school's Algebra I course about the school's expectations in these areas.  You might be able to find such a parent through your school's Parent Teacher Association.

Comment: What if health care worked the way schools do? They might occasionally grudgingly admit that not all patients are identical.

Comment: Most public schools will not accommodate for a 7th grader in Algebra 2.  If your son is this far ahead, you should consider either home schooling or an exceptional private school.  I am a public school teacher so I'm normally partial to public schools, but we simply don't have the resources or time to accommodate extreme exceptionality.  I wish it were different.

Answer (score 2):

You can find information about how Pennsylvania handles acceleration in education at this address.

http://www.accelerationinstitute.org/Resources/Policy/By_State/Show_Policy.aspx?StateID=45

If you truly want your son placed in Algebra II, you may need to consider educational alternatives if the local school board is not accommodating. Considering the schedule for Algebra II may conflict with the rest of his classes, it might be more difficult for them than just the evaluation, which in itself should not be difficult at all.